# Angular setting form with scope?

Tags: angularjs, forms

What I want is a form that I can use for both creating and updating. So I pass before showing

```
$scope.form = {};

$scope.car = null;
$scope.getCar = function(hash) {
  $http.get('/cars/'+hash).success(function(car) {
      $scope.car = car;
      $scope.form = car;
  });
};
```

As you can see I add the result of the get to both car and form.
Now I'm opening the View:

```
<h1>{{ form.name }} <small>shows correctly</small></h1>
```

But a line after that I'm trying almost the same:

```
<form class="list" ng-submit="createOrUpdateForm(form)">

    <label class="item">
        <span class="input-label">Name</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.name">
```

Here it's not shown... But when I add the same line after it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="car.name">
```

This does work, but then I can't use the ng-submit anymore, because that references to form.

Form some reason I can't set the form scope?

Comment: confusing what is going on since you overwrite the initial object with `car`. Is `car` an object? Also not sure what you need 2 scope variables with same `car` value. Create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manual assigning anything to `form`. A "form" is not the same as the data you manage using the form. Neither the empty object `{}` nor `car` make sense in that context.

Give the form a name, this will allow angular to assign it to a scope property.

```
<h1>{{ car.name }} <small>shows correctly</small></h1>

<form name="carForm" ng-submit="createOrUpdateForm(carForm)">

    <label class="item">
        <span class="input-label">Name</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="car.name">
```

---

```
$scope.createOrUpdateForm = function(form) {
    if(form.$valid) {
        console.log($scope.car.name);
        // POST / PUT your data.
    }
};
```